# How to map a 4 character long string made of 10 possible characters to a range between 1 and 10000 in a shuffled way?

Tags: c#, encryption

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

1. I have characters DISCOUNT23
2. I generate codes out of these like DNT2 or CTDI

- There is 10,000 possible codes

3. I want 100 of these codes to be valid
4. I want to map 10,000 possible strings to numbers between 1 and 10,000
5. I want to make first 100 numbers to be valid

- If string DISC is mapped to 175 it is NOT valid
- If string DIS3 is mapped to 23 it is valid

I want this mapping to be secret but not random so I don't want to store valid codes in a database but I also don't want code DISC to be mapped to 1234 or DIS3 mapped to 1230

Basically, I want to encrypt codes made out of characters DISCOUNT23 into numbers between 1 and 10,000, so when I encrypt a code like 23DS I want to get a number like 27 and when I decrypt the number 27 I want to get the code 23DS

Comment: So 4 (as in title) or 5 characters (as in question)?

Comment: 4 characters, fixed the error

Comment: You can use random number generator with fixed seed. That way from outside it will look completely random for someone who doesn't know the seed. And you can generate the mapping when needed (on service startup or something), same every time, so database is not needed. Works because the number of entries is small (just 10k) so no problem to generate and store in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My class encrypts and decrypts on a character-by-character basis. The character mappings are rotated in a modulo 10 fashion depending on the character position:

```
internal class Mapper
    {
        const string CodeChars = "DISCOUNT23";  //  10 characters
        const int CodeLen = 4;                  //  10^4 possible words

        public static int Encrypt(string code)
        {
            Debug.Assert(code.Length == CodeLen);

            int w = 0;

            for (int pos = 0; pos < CodeLen; pos++)
            {
                //  every char in code word gets
                //  a value according to the CodeChars
                char c = code[pos];
                int cVal = CodeChars.IndexOf(c);
                Debug.Assert(cVal >= 0);

                //  values are altered dependent on the position
                cVal = (cVal + pos + 7) % 10;
                w = 10 * w + cVal;
            }

            return w;
        }

        public static string Decrypt(int val)
        {
            string s = "";

            for (int pos = 0; pos < CodeLen; pos++)
            {
                int p = (val % 10);

                int v = (p + 14 - CodeLen + pos) % 10;

                s = CodeChars[v] + s;

                val /= 10;
            }

            return s;
        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            string[] words = {"DISC", "ISC3", "23DS" };

            foreach(var w in words)
            {
                var e = Encrypt(w);
                var d = Decrypt(e);
                Debug.WriteLine($"{w} ==> {e} ==> {d}");
                //  Debug.Assert(d == w);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var d = Decrypt(i);
                var e = Encrypt(d);
                Debug.WriteLine($"{i} ==> {d} ==> {e}");
                Debug.Assert(i == e);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("ciao!");
        }
    }
```

Results of the test code:

```
DISC ==> 7913 ==> DISC
ISC3 ==> 8029 ==> ISC3
23DS ==> 5792 ==> 23DS
1 ==> CSII ==> 1
2 ==> CSIS ==> 2
3 ==> CSIC ==> 3
4 ==> CSIO ==> 4
5 ==> CSIU ==> 5
6 ==> CSIN ==> 6
7 ==> CSIT ==> 7
8 ==> CSI2 ==> 8
9 ==> CSI3 ==> 9
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I tried to tinker with it a bit, tried to add new chars (13 characters instead of 10) and change length (5 instead of 4) but that seem to be breaking it. If I wanted to change from modulo 10 to 13 (or let's just say use mdoulo X), what would I be doing?

Comment: Going away from 10 characters is not trivial. My method is digit-oriented and thus tied to 10. It might be simpler to use a fixed-seed random number generator as recommended in the comment by @Evk. To change the length from 4 to 5 is easy. Just change the constant `CodeLen` as desired.